# WebDriverEventListener FindingElement get By with selector

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I use the EventFiringWebDriver#FindingElement Method and want to get the By with the Selector. Is this even possible?

this is my EventListener

```
    public class WebDriverEventListener : EventFiringWebDriver
    {

        public WebDriverEventListener(IWebDriver parentDriver) : base(parentDriver)
        {

            ExceptionThrown += (sender, e) =>
            {

            };

            ElementClicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("ClickElement: ").Append(e.Element);
                Trace.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            };

            FindingElement += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("Findelement: ").Append(e.Element);
                Trace.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            };
        }
}
```

If I you this like this everything is fine. The Tests run and finding the Elements as expected.

But If I want to get the TagName from the Element in FindingElement I can't because Element is null? But why?

Answer (score 0):

That method takes a FindElementArgs parameter which has a constructor taking a By selector

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_By.htm

This, in turn supports a TagName method.

So its certainly possible.

So the obvious question is, is the element on page?

Comment: Yes It is, but the EventListener don't get it.